# How to position DIV on top and absolute in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, html, positioning

Can anyone give me an idea how div positioning works in JQuery?

I want to show a div at an absolute position and on top of everything else? Like in a form I want to show a help pop-up to appear right next to the text box in focus (like they do in careers.stackoverflow > edit CV) .

Similarly what is the best strategy to show a hover card like when in twitter when you hover over an avatar a small div appears with user profile summary.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#imgLinkToolTip').mouseover(function() {
        $('#dvLinkToolTip').css({ left: $(this).position().left - 300, top: $(this).position().top - 45 }).show();
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $('#dvLinkToolTip').hide();
    });
});
```

In this example, imgLinkToolTip is your hover-over target and dvLinkTooltip is the div that you'd like to pop-up.

And yes, your div will need a higher z-order and position: absolute.

Comment: this is good. i wanted a homegrown option rather than using an external library. thanks

Answer (score 2):

The div you want to position on top needs a higher z-order, position: absolute, and dimensions.

I have used plugins like [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) to provide the functionality you are mentioning in the past. There are probably a 100 other tooltip plugins that would work too.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the "hover card", I recommend looking into the [qTip Plugin](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip).

Answer (score 0):

Positioning the div is done just like you would do without javascript/jQuery. So, I would start by creating an actual coded and working HTML/CSS demo of what you want to do. Position your jQuery activated content in its own (absolutely) positioned div. Once it looks ok (checking multiple browsers, etc), then you can just show/hide the div, and you won't need to worry about custom positioning it with jQuery.

Alternatively, you're trying to position the jQuery activated content on the fly (so, the content isn't already loaded in the page, etc), you may need to set inline styles `$('#mydiv').css()` setting absolute positioning values (top, left, etc).

Answer (score 0):

For positioning

try with css style  fields  top:5px; left:px;As you want

Try to use FF fireBug and check whats really happening

Try

position:absolute and position:relative

For hover or layering!!

use  z-index and position

Try Jquery slide ,slideDown for effects